# Perceptron class causes Typeerror when I use numpy.dot

Tags: python, numpy, class, neural-network

I am currently trying to get into machine learning but I'm stuck at the implementation of the update.
My current code so far is

```
import numpy as np
```

class MCP():

```
def __init__(self, features=4, labels=3, epochs=250, learning_rate=0.1):
    self.f = features
    self.l = labels
    self.N = epochs
    self.lr = learning_rate
    self.weights = self.initialize_weights() 

def initialize_weights(self):
    weights = np.zeros(self.f)
    return weights

def train(self, train):
    for i in range(self.N):
        for example in train:
            label= example[4]
            doc  = example[0:4]
            prediction = np.dot(doc, self.weights)
            if prediction != label:
                self.weights += self.lr * (label - prediction) * doc
            else:
                weights = weights
    return weights
```

but the code already complainst at the prediction part.

```
 a=train[0]
 print(a)
 >> ['4.9', '3.0', '1.4', '0.2', '0 ']
```

I want my prediction do make the dotproduct of a[0:4] and my weights [0. 0. 0. 0.]

This error appears

```
TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching typesdtype (<U3) dtype (<U3) dtype (<U3)
```

I looked the error up but still can't figure out how to solve my problem.

I believe that the problem lies in my a since they appear to be string entries and I think that stops the dotproduct to happen.

Comment: You can't use `dot/matmul` with strings.  It requires objects that can multiply and sum.  You need to pay more attention to the `dtype` of the inputs to this function.  See the quotes in the `print(a)`?  That means `train` (the array) contains strings, not numbers.

Comment: It isn't causing problems, but I'd suggest using a different name for the `train` function.

Comment: How should I convert my list with string entries the wanted type? I tried some converts but all failed so far

Comment: `np.array(a, float)` should produce a numeric array.